Speed of light along $y$ and $z$ axes when there is relative motion
There are two coordinate systems. One is stationary and the other moves in the positive $x$-direction with a speed of $v$. I don't know how to interpret the $\sqrt{V^2 - v^2}$ term since light always has a speed of $c=V$--this is a principle, no?
I could apply the Pythagorean Theorem. The form of the term suggests that $V$ is the magnitude of a velocity vector forming a hypotenuse. The form also suggests there is a velocity vector of magnitude $v$ that reaches this hypotenuse at an angle less than 90 degrees, which doesn't follow the situation in the text.
If anything, the minus sign should be a plus. Insights? I'm confused as to why Einstein would make such an obvious mistake in such an important paper. The resulting equations look correct but the explanation seems very off. The velocity of the light is wrong. However, the physical situation of light traveling along a different axis is promising.

Sources:
https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/~rtaylor/teaching/specrel.pdf
https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/161

Yes, you are correct, the speed of light is constant in all frames; this is one of the basic postulates of relativity. However, you have to bear with Einstein for a few more pages of the papers, because he is attempting to prove that the postulate of constancy of the speed of light is consistent with the relativity principle, i.e. that the laws of physics are the same in all inertial frames. This is the reason that he appears to loosen the requirement that light travels at the speed $V$ in all frames. He will later show that it does indeed travel in all frames with speed $V$ and that the postulate is consistent with the relativity principle.

@Christina Daniel As far as the weird square root of the differences of the velocities, see pages 144-145 of the document, he is transposing a specific equation there that is manipulated in the subsequent formulae leading up to the derivation you are working with.

Let's just say I fall more into the 'mathematician' category than the 'physicist' category...

@ChristinaDaniel  I love mathematics, it was my dream to become a mathematical physicist, however, I fear I am much more of a physicist than a mathematician. Are you doing this as part of a formal university study?

I'm preparing for a postdoc that I'll apply to in a year or sooner.

@ChristinaDaniel Awesome, Good Luck to you in all of your endeavors!

Thank you. Same to you!

Einstein was talking about the velocity components of light propagating in the vertical direction. In frame k, the light source is at rest and light is emitted only in the y-direction, thus we evidently have
$$V_{x}=0,\ V_{y}=V$$
where $V$ is the speed of light.
We obtain the components in frame K in which the light source moves by speed $v$ in the x-direction as follows: The velocity component of light in x-direction is evidently
$$V_{x}^{\prime}=v$$
and by assuming that the speed of light is also constant in this frame, it follows from the Pythagorean theorem,
$$V^{2}=v^{2}+V_{y}^{\prime2}$$
or solving for $V_{y}^{\prime}$ we obtain Einstein's result
$$\sqrt{V^{2}-v^{2}}$$
indicating the light speed component on the perpendicular Y or Z axis (note that Einstein used H instead of Y).
So Einstein's result is perfectly consistent with constant light speed, if we remember the this constancy is defined by
$$c^{2}=c_{x}^{2}+c_{y}^{2}$$
where only $c$ has to be constant, but $c_x$ and $c_y$ are variable. You will also notice that the same light speed components also appear in computations of the light clock.
